# Identity axiom for a sheaf

Tags: definition, sheaf-theory

In the definition of a sheaf, the identity axiom is usually stated:

> If $g,h\in \mathcal{F}(U)$ and $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $U$ and $\rho^U_{U_i}g=\rho^U_{U_i}h$ for each $i\in I$, then $g=h$.

It seems by writing $\rho^U_{U_i}$ they actually mean $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$, else we may have for some $i\in I$ that $U_i\cap U\ne\emptyset$ in which case the restriction map doesn't exist. We really mean $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ in this axiom right?

Comment: You're right - "cover"  only means containment in topology (at least as per one quick google check), doesn't it?  But "cover" here means your union: in particular, the $U_i\subset U$, and the restriction maps are defined.  I would say this 'non-standard' use of 'cover' is standard in this area.  (I have to say I kinda disagree with the [spirit of the] answer below...)

Comment: FWIW, the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics) has a link to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology), which uses the "contains" meaning of cover. Hartshorne, on the other hand, doesn't seem to  define "cover." Griffiths and Harris are 'almost' more careful and compare ${\cal F} (U \cup V)$ to ${\cal F}(U)$ and ${\cal F}(V)$ in their def of sheaves (p. 35). In any case, if only from the (pre)-sheaves are functors point of view, they all agree that the restriction maps are (only) defined  if one open set is a sub of the other.

Comment: And then there are https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/006C and https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/006S

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** this answer is based on a misreading of the question.

Even if they mean $\bigcup U_i=U$, that doesn't solve the problem, as one of the $U_i$ may be empty. Since the empty set of a topological space is, by convention, open, a presheaf must "know" what are the functions on the empty set, and how to restrict any function to the empty set.

But this is easy. There is one function on the empty set: the empty function. Every function restricts to it. So it's not correct that $\rho^U_{U_i}$ doesn't exist if $U_i$ is empty or disjoint from $U$. It exists, it just restricts everything to one map: the empty map.

It's not required for presheaves restrict everything to a unique element on the empty set, but in fact you can show using the identity axiom that $\mathcal{F}(\varnothing)=*$ for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}.$

Comment: I am confused, I didn't mean that $U_i$ was necessarily empty/disjoint, but perhaps we could have $U_i\cap U\ne\emptyset$, so that $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i \supsetneq U$ where then we don't get a map $\rho^U_{U_i}$ since that would require our contravariant functor to map some $U_i\hookrightarrow U$ to this $\rho^U_{U_i}$, and $U_i$ may not be contained within $U$

Comment: @Fredrieck yes, I'm sorry. I think I misread your question. I must have seen $U\cap U_i=\varnothing$ when instead you wrote $U\cap U_i\neq\varnothing$. So then... you (and peter in the comments) are right. It means $U=\bigcup U_i.$ You do need there to be inclusion maps $U_i\to U$ for every $U_i$